# How to setup twill for python 2.6 on Windows?

Tags: python

I have already downloaded twill 0.9. Also, I have installed easy_install for python 2.6. Now I'm stuck with twill installation. Could you help me to settle the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
easy_install twill
```

It assumes you have easy_install in your PATH, which is the case on unix, but not on windows. On windows, the easy_install script can be found in C:\Python25\Scripts

Answer (score 1):

easiest way is to just unzip the twill and keep it somewhere in PYTHONPATH e.g. in your project and just import twill

else copy twill folder directly to D:\Python26\Lib\site-packages

Comment: I do not recommend this in general, since the installation of a package might have some other hooks than just copying a folder. e.g. it could run the testsuite, download some package data from the web, compile a C extension, etc.